# Angular Multiple Page Routing with Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean

So if I have a full MEAN stack going and I am using a view engine (ejs) to render my pages, what angular/javascript method can I use to load up a new page.

Currently I have in my Express 
`app.get('/page2', function(req, res, next){  res.render('newPage'); });`

I have my `newPage.ejs` in my view folder and in my index.ejs page I call a `$http.get('/page2')` to get the render, but it returns the HTML but never loads it up.

Ideally I would want to make a post request so I can use the body to fill in some ejs variables

currently using window.location, but I feel that is defeating the purpose of the MEAN stack

**SOLUTION:**
So I was mixing up "Page routing" and "Single page applications"

If you are planning on loading a new page without refreshing the web page then you shouldn't be calling your sever, instead you should have an Angular single page using ngRoute or of that nature and if I want I can send a post request to Express, get the results and fill them in that way.

Comment: Clarify a bit? Or better, show index.ejs and newPage.ejs (minimal working examples) so we can see what't not loading.

Comment: It is not that my ejs pages aren't loading the html, its that my browser won't load up the page, but if I type in `localhost:3000/page2` it loads, so why doesn't it load when I call it from my http request, I can verify that its getting called as if I do a `.success(function(data){console.log(data)})` it shows the entire ejs page in my browser console

Comment: Still not clear - your console.log(data) on the client is giving you a raw ejs file? Not compiled?

Comment: Sorry, it is compiled in the log, but I want it to display it. So if I have a button to "go to page 2" it would open up that file and load up page 2, so instead of a single page application with states, I want to have the option to have a few different single page application all under one big application

Comment: Your `$http.get('/page2')` - can you, just for test, replace it with `window.location = '/page2'? Does it render then? It looks like a router problem. Do you use ng-route, or ui-router or something like that?

Comment: yes, a window.location routes me over, its not ideal, but it works. Also I use ui-router, but that routes states between the same application page unless I am not aware of some its functions

Comment: Ok then, it's simple - you want to switch to page2, you trigger the router. That's what it's there for. Not fetching the page with $http, but doing a $state.go('/page2') with the ui-router. Or am I not understanding something correclty?

Comment: You are right, I think I just finally understand how servers and routing works now, didn't realize it was just this simple